# md-tab with partial scroll-y

Tags: angular, angular2-material

In this example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/aPyAkWKEVcFl0xcLpIQm?p=preview

```
<div class="containerColumn">

<div style="flex: 0 1 auto;">
  <md-toolbar color="accent" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
    <span>TITULO DE LA PANTALLA DE SCROLL PARCIAL</span>
  </md-toolbar>
</div>

<md-tab-group md-stretch-tabs>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>
      <md-icon>chat</md-icon>
    </template>

    <div  style="flex: 0 1 auto; padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;">
      <textarea style="background-color:black;color:white; width: 90%;"></textarea>
      <i class="material-icons orange600" style="cursor:pointer; " (click)="crear()">send</i>
    </div>
    <div  style="flex: 1 1 auto; overflow: auto;">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, eum voluptates cupiditate tempore in numquam iure dolor delectus a dignissimos velit nesciunt mollitia voluptatem molestiae placeat repudiandae ea nostrum autem!</li>
.....
        <li>Aliquam, dicta, eos pariatur illum praesentium aut doloribus omnis cupiditate quas dolorem. Consequatur incidunt commodi eos voluptatum! Pariatur, eaque ut accusamus. Fugiat, qui repellendus praesentium animi ratione deserunt et illo!</li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>
      <md-icon>content_paste</md-icon>
    </template>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, expedita, voluptatem dolores id quos ea libero nam culpa esse maxime dolorem alias impedit consectetur ad voluptate quibusdam reiciendis! Veritatis, ex.
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>
      <md-icon>phone</md-icon>
    </template>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>
      <md-icon>picture_as_pdf</md-icon>
      pdf
    </template>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

I need to scroll the chat items by keeping the textarea fixed.
I have tried it in many ways and I do not get the expected result.

Can someone help me?

Regards.